# Transform List from {a,a,b,b,b,c} to {{a,2},{b,3},{c,1}}

Tags: list-manipulation, counting

The title pretty much says it. I want to map over the solutions returned by Solve but want to avoid calculating the same thing over and over again.

e.g.

```
sol = Solve[(x - 1)^4*(x + 1)^7 == 0, x]
(*=>{{x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, 
     {x -> -1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 1}, {x -> 1}}*)
heavyTask[#] &/@ sol
```

However, I would like to keep track of the number of solutions. Therefore, I thought the best way would be to have

```
sol={{{x -> 1},4}}
```

The only way I have been able to do it

```
DeleteDuplicates[{#, Count[sol, #]} & /@ sol]
```

As you can see my solution is calling `Count` for every element in the list. This usually isn't a problem as I work with small lists only. Nevertheless I could imagine that there are better ways to do it?

Comment: Check out the Tally command. http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Tally.html?q=Tally

Comment: That was easy. I need to work on my google skills. Didn't come across this command.

Comment: @Mr Z why not to formulate your comment as an answer? Otherwise this question will stay without answer forever.

Comment: I think this is not easily found in the documentation. One would need to know what to search for and "tally" does not immediately come to mind. In more recent versions were also have `Counts` (which is a more intuitive name). If the question were not closed, someone could post that as an answer as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Gustavo pointed out in the comments above there is already a build-in function in Mathematica which does exactly what I asked for:

```
Tally[Solve[(x - 1)^4*(x + 1)^7 == 0, x]]
(*=>{{{x -> -1}, 7}, {{x -> 1}, 4}}*)
```